# Setting (or changing) the ACL for an object in an S3 bucket using put_acl() in R?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

`get_acl()` returns a string representation of XML showing the current ACL. This works as expected.

According to `?put_acl` and [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html), I should be able to edit the ACL and `put_acl()` to set a new one.

#### Example

Suppose we insert a new `grant` inside the existing ACL to give public read access to an object in a bucket

```
library(aws.s3)
original_acl <- get_acl("object_name", "bucket_name") 

public_access_grant <- '<Grant><Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Group"><URI>http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers</URI> </Grantee><Permission>READ</Permission></Grant>'

# Split existing ACL into two
original_acl_part_1 <- substr(original, 1, nchar(original) - 42)
original_acl_part_2 <- substr(original,  nchar(original) - 42 + 1, nchar(original))

# Paste the chunks back together with the new grant included
new_acl_in_xml_as_a_string <- paste0(original_part_1, public_access_grant, original_part_2)
```

At this point, I should be able to set the new ACL, like so

```
put_acl(object=object_name, bucket=bucket_name, body=new_acl_in_xml_as_a_string)
```

#### Unexpected result

A quick test using `get_acl()` shows the ACL hasn't changed from its original

#### Question

What's going on and why wasn't the ACL updated as expected?